# Convert an animation to .js to use it in three.js

Tags: json, three.js, converters, blender

Hello I am making my first steps with JavaScript and playing with three.js too.

Even if its loaded with the json loader the animation of this example http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_horse is a .js and not a .json and it looks like this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/horse.js

How can I get a file like this one from an animation made with Blender? For the moment I know that I have a three.js exporter to json but not to js. Or maybe there is a way to transform json to js?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Javascript/WebGL world!

### JSON vs JS

- JSON == JavaScript Object Notation (Data to read)
- JS == Javascript (Code to run)

Two different things. JS is code; JSON is a string representation of an object (in this case, meshes, morphs, etc). Check out the [JSON official site](http://www.json.org/) or Google for a gentler introduction.

In examples, JS is:

```
var x = 0.1;
console.log(Math.floor(x));
```

while JSON looks like:

```
{
  "obj": "cool",
  "count": 1
}
```

Of extra interest to you would be the [horse file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/models/animated/horse.js) **is** JSON, just with a .js extension. That's what I get out of the three.js exporter. The async function doesn't care about the extension (could be "horse.foo"); three.js just tries to GET the file at the URL provided and parse the string as a JSON (that matches three.js' format).

### Duplicating the Animation

Jump straight to the [codepen example](http://codepen.io/erik0077/pen/YyobOv?editors=011) to the TL;DR.

Using a three.js example as a starting point is great. I tend to use local servers for this, in the long run they don't last (I turn them off, they catch on fire, etc). So I've cooked up a copy of the [horse example on codepen](http://codepen.io/erik0077/pen/rOEgZW). It's just a complete clone of your referenced example, but with codepen resources. I'd start by forking that and working from there.

Sounds as if you have some success with getting the [blender three.js exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender) working, so I'd run with that. You can post that JSON as another codepen and reference it as I have in this [(slightly modified) fork](http://codepen.io/erik0077/pen/YyobOv?editors=011).

For my example, I threw together this [animated ... thing](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=87902792339469479330) (an artist I'm not). Note how the animation in question runs from frame 0-30, same as the code calls for with the line:

```
var clip = THREE.AnimationClip.CreateFromMorphTargetSequence('gallop', geometry.morphTargets, 30);
```

Hopefully that clears up your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer really helps me to understand it!!

Comment: Now I can understand the var clip and the animation that runs from frame 0-30 but I am trying the same with this animation s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07429365581548704592 and it doesnt work, even if I correctly wrote the number of frames. Do you know why? thank you for your help @user01

Comment: @gnazoa Neat animation and mats. Wish I had your blender skills. Bad news is I don't think this will fly, as is. This is enormous at 23Mb and 130k(!!) faces. And the cycles mats won't export to three.js json. A blind export of the 'level3' obj = 150Mb. While not impossible, I would call this unreasonable for three.js. But, say you're undeterred: lower your poly count and create your mat in three.js (another topic altogether). That subsurf is hurting more than helping after ~70. Start simpler, get a demo working, and then crank everything up until you can't stand the filesize/polys/framerate